# convert .zip file into NSData

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, nsstring, zip, nsdata

Hey, Is it correct to initialize an NSData with a zip file? I want to convert a zip file into NSData and construct another file with the data (in simple language 'copy it'). I have the code as:

```
NSURL *theFileUrl = [NSURL URLWithString: @"file://localhost/Users/xxx/Desktop/testZippedFile.zip"];

NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: theFileUrl];
```

When I, `NSLog(@"Data: %@", data)` , i do get some output but when I try to initialize an NSString with this data, it doesn't work:

```
 NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: data encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
`NSLog(@"String: %@", string)`
```

I get the log as: `String: PK`

Can anyone point out my mistakes please.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: er, why on earth do you want to create a string from it? That doesn't match your problem description.

Comment: hey :) i'm new to iPhone SDK so I'm trying all the dumb things. I thought to copy a file onto the system, i could convert the file into a string and then write this string to another file (okay, that was kinda stupid)... But now as deanWombourne has suggested, i'll try with NSFilaManager.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why do it that way? [NSFileManager](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html) will do it for you :)

```
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:oldPath toPath:newPath error:nil];
```

---

However, this only works for files that are local - if you want to copy a file from a server, you should have a look at [NSURLConnection](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to load the data and then NSData's writeToFile:atomically: method to save the contents to the file system ([found here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html).)

Comment: Hey, i'm testing my code in the simulator. I tried copyItemAtPath: for where both source and destination files are on the local machine and it worked perfectly fine. But when I set the source path as some URL say "http://someServer/someDirectory/zippedFile.zip", it gives an error : No such file or directory. Could you please tell me what is going wrong here?

Comment: You can't use this to copy from a server to your device - I assumed that you just wanted to move a file around after you had downloaded it. See my edit for other solutions

Comment: thanks... i did something of the sort...
NSString *pathForFile = [NSString stringWithString: @"http://someServer/someDirectory/zippedFile.zip"];
NSString *pathForDestination = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"temp.zip"];
NSURL *urlForFile = [NSURL URLWithString: pathForFile];
NSData *zipFileData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: urlForFile];
[zipFileData writeToFile: pathForDestination options: NSDataWritingAtomic error:&error]

Comment: it works ok...but i think i'll have to work on the NSURLConnection thing... Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

*PK* is the output you should expect.
The first 2 Characters in every zip-file are PK. Then there are some unprintable chars and at some point after those there is a character with a value of 0
If you create an NSString out of NSData all values up to the first 0-value are taken into account.

**NEVER** convert binary data into NSString.