# Cocoa POST Request with file

Tags: cocoa, post

Is it possible to submit a file from within Cocoa? What I mean is that I have a file on the client's side which I want uploaded to my server as if I selected it in a upload field in HTML. Then, I need to show the response the server sent in a text field.

Is this possible at all, and if so, can I show the progress on a progress bar? I do have the code to send a regular POST request, but I just don't know how to go about sending a file effectively to a server-side PHP script.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can submit a content of a file like this:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://"]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"text/xml" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-type"];

NSString *xmlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@"];

[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [xmlString length]]
forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-length"];

[request setHTTPBody:[xmlString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

Response served by your PHP script can be retrieved by delegates (all must be implemented, see **NSURLConnection** documentation for details, there is an example):

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse*)response
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
```

Comment: This seems to only work for text files... what about files like ZIP Archives?

Comment: setHTTPBody accepts any NSData object, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3891149/convert-zip-file-into-nsdata